# Discord Only you can see this message

Tags: discord.py

I wanted to get messages from a channel but the messages I want to get are these messages „only you can see this message“.
I tried to get the messages with this request url: https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/966052113174102093/messages?limit=25, but I don’t get the hidden messages.

Comment: could you be more clear on what do you mean by "hidden messages" as your bot should have access to the channel you're targeting other than that you will receive "401: Unauthorized message"

Comment: @MrKioZ I made a program that click in a channel on a embed button. If I clicked on the button, I should get a message which says this message can only see you but if I want to get the messages of the channel, I can’t see the message which only I can see. In my browser with my account, if I click the button the messag which only I can see appears but if I reload it’s gone and I have to click again this message. So my question is how do I get the message from the channel

Comment: @Schlenni123 when you reload the message is gone. There is no way around that. I guess you could maybe do DMs or maybe even make a private channel to send the message in

Answer (score 5):

These types of messages are called ephemeral messages. You can make a message ephemeral only if it is from an interaction (buttons, slash commands, drop-down menus).

`await interaction.response.send_message(content=content, ephemeral=True)`

Add `ephemeral=True` after the content, this should work **only with [interactions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=interactions)**.